# Trying to Pluralize in C# I get 'Entity' does not exist in System.Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I have a T4 template include that starts like this:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>

<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>

string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Host.TemplateFile);
```

When I try to add a reference to Pluralizer, like this:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices" #>

<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>

string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Host.TemplateFile);
string pluralTable = PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-US")).Pluralize(tableName);
```

I get the message:

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I do reference System.Data.Entity.Design in the Project. We are using EF6.

Comment: Are you missing the assembly reference `<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity.Design" #>`?

Comment: Yup, that was you. I was just refreshing myself on the differences between including assemblies vs namespaces.